# X tries until getting 2 consecutive succeses

Tags: probability, random-variables

Literally this question made me wonder if I will ever get to a solution .
Okay so  ,  we have a machine that we want to start up , in order for that , we must keep starting it up until we obtain 2 consecutive startups (S for success) .
I mean it is fairly easy to describe in English.

And X is the random variable of how many start ups did it take .

Now of course I realized the important things , that made my problem so much harder ( Which I took the dumb approach and be done with it) .

Anyway  suppose We have  X=x  then we have  (_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _)FSS as a way to view the result with _ being a place to put S or F(failure start up)
now before FSS there are of course  x-3 gaps to fill as I said before , and I wrote FSS not SS because of course the one before cannot be an S (the smart assumption I realized) .  But now I m just hitting my head by the hugeness of this problem , I mean there is no number to how many singular S's there are in those x-3 spaces , should I like sum it for the previouses S's ? And even crazier the book says a hint , to write the probability mass function recursively and I was like waaaaa (i know recursion , but im not seeing the recursion in this problem ) 
Help plz

HUGE FYI  p of success is 0.9

The problem is to find P(X<=8) It can be done manually as in counting each way , but I want to know about this recursion business.

Comment: You are looking for the expected value of $X$, right?

Comment: No just P(X<=8) It can be done manually as in counting each way , but I want to know about this recursion business

Comment: You didn't even say what are the probabilities of $F$ and $S$... I can't understand what is the request

Comment: extremely sorry , forgot about that , im gonna re edit

Comment: You should say in your question what is the request, people shouldn't need to read the comments to know it!

Comment: Ok so you solved it by counting and you would like to know if there are other ways of computing $P(X<8)$? It seems to me that it isn't so long to get the result by counting.

Comment: Yes maybe by finding a relation between the Probability of X and X-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P_n$ denote the probability of getting $SS$ on the $n_{th}$ trial,

then $P_{n} - P_{n-1}$ means that you get $SS$ for the first time   on the $n_{th}$ trial only,

which means that you must have failed on the $(n-3)_{th}$ trial, and got an F immediately after that, e.g. for $P_8$, you must be a failure at $P_5$ and get an F on the $6_{th}$ trial followed by $SS$

Using the usual notation of $p$ and $q$ for probabilities of success/failure for *individual* trials,
$P_{n} - P_{n-1} = [1 - P_{n-3}]qp^2$ for $n\ge3$

Starting conditions are: $P_0 = 0, P_1 = 0, P_2 = 0.81, P_3 = 0.081$

Proceed.....